# Tabhost tabs don't display correctly across devices

Tags: android, textview, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-tabhost, horizontalscrollview

I'm experiencing weird behavior in a tabhost across different devices. Which leads me to think there is a problem with the device (considering the one giving me trouble is running an unofficial mod) but I thought I'd ask anyway.

My tabs are inside a HorizontalScrollView with the intention that they will extend past the allotted space but allow the user to reach them.

Here's my code

**Activity**

```
    // Set up Tabs
    TabHost tabs = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.my_tabhost);
    tabs.setup();


    TabSpec tspec1 = tabs.newTabSpec("items");
    tspec1.setIndicator(makeTabView("Items", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.basket_icon_light)));
    tspec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    tabs.addTab(tspec1);
    TabSpec tspec2 = tabs.newTabSpec("customers");
    tspec2.setIndicator(makeTabView("Customers", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.customer_icon_light)));
    tspec2.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    tabs.addTab(tspec2);
    TabSpec tspec3 = tabs.newTabSpec("dept");
    tspec3.setIndicator(makeTabView("Departments", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.dept_icon_light)));
    tspec3.setContent(R.id.tab3);
    tabs.addTab(tspec3);
    TabSpec tspec4 = tabs.newTabSpec("users");
    tspec4.setIndicator(makeTabView("Users", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.user_icon_light)));
    tspec4.setContent(R.id.tab4);
    tabs.addTab(tspec4);
    tabs.setOnTabChangedListener(tabchange);
    TabSpec tspec5 = tabs.newTabSpec("terms");
    tspec5.setIndicator(makeTabView("Terms", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.terms_icon_light)));
    tspec5.setContent(R.id.tab5);
    tabs.addTab(tspec5);
    tabs.setOnTabChangedListener(tabchange);



private View makeTabView(String name, Drawable draw){
    View v = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.setMargins(1, 0, 1, 0);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.tab_image);
    TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tab_text);
    image.setImageDrawable(draw);
    text.setText(name);
    v.setLayoutParams(lp);
    v.setBackgroundDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tabindicator));
    return v;
}
```

**CustomTab.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal" 
  android:layout_height="match_parent" 
  android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
              android:orientation="vertical" 
              android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" 
              android:layout_marginRight="20dp" 
              android:layout_height="match_parent" 
              android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/tab_image" 
               android:src="@drawable/icon" 
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
               android:layout_gravity="center" 
               android:scaleType="centerInside" 
               android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    </ImageView>
    <TextView android:layout_gravity="center" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:id="@+id/tab_text" 
              android:text="TextView" 
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_marginBottom="10px">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**TabHost.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/contain_nav" 
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                  android:orientation="horizontal" 
                  android:background="@drawable/border_top">
        <TabHost android:id="@+id/my_tabhost" 
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout android:weightSum="100" 
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                          android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                          android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
                          android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                              android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                              android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">
                    <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                                          android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView2" 
                                          android:fillViewport="true" 
                                          android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                                          android:scrollbars="none">
                        <TabWidget android:orientation="horizontal" 
                                   android:id="@android:id/tabs" 
                                   android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                                   android:layout_width="wrap_content">
                        </TabWidget>
                    </HorizontalScrollView>
                </LinearLayout>
                <FrameLayout android:layout_height="0dp" 
                             android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                             android:id="@android:id/tabcontent">
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                                  android:layout_height="0dp" 
                                  android:id="@+id/tab1">
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                                  android:layout_height="0dp" 
                                  android:id="@+id/tab2">
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                                  android:id="@+id/tab3">
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                                  android:id="@+id/tab4">
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                                  android:id="@+id/tab5">
                    </LinearLayout>
                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </TabHost>
    </LinearLayout>
```

And here's what it should look like
[(Mot XOOM)](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/WQ_Z20LEDF14pqRe_rmeMEb1dOEZIzRgRIQzt_Z2WTI?feat=directlink)
Here's what I keep getting
[(Viewsonic Gtablet)](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/uU_lytnGKK-puBRum4LZdEb1dOEZIzRgRIQzt_Z2WTI?feat=directlink)

Am I missing something I know pixel density can affect how things render, but I just don't get this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Its matter of screen density. Create tabs background images on the same layer you did the image for `Customers`. 
I'm not into designing icons and image resources for this purpose, but I have given the link below to someone who is into graphics and he did the job well.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_tab.html

Comment: Here's the thing... all icons were designed pretty much the same what your seeing is the result of `scaletype="centerInside` for some reason `width="wrap_content` isn't holding on the gTab... I even set the images View.GONE to test it and the text still didn't show only when I set the width to 200dp did it work somewhat

Comment: Could you show the my_tabhost xml? Because the isue might lie inside that xml, not in customtab xml

Comment: And I want to have a look on the `TabWidget` in that xml

Comment: Ok its up... did see a `weightsum=100` that doesn't need to be there (leftover from different attempts at a working scrollview) Unfortunately I left the gtab at work so I can't test till tomorrow. But why the difference between the XOOM and the gtab

Answer (score 0):

It's actually problem with honeycomb 3.0 and the horizantalscrollview. This seems to be fixed with 3.1 and higher. I used the method of removing the scroll view in a layout and putting it in layout-mdpi-v11 folder and then putting the xml layout with the scroll view in layout-mdpi-v12.

Not the best work around but as of the time of this writing 3.0 only covers 0.2% of active devices.